# redirectUrl in Chrome apps?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

With Chrome extensions can be done, but it will be possible with Chrome apps?

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (info) {
    return {redirectUrl: "http://www.newurl.com/file.js"};
}, {
    urls: ["*://www.originalurl.com/file.js"]
},
["blocking"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The list of supported APIs in apps: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index

Besides, ideologically apps are self-contained and should not interact with the normal browsing.

---

Update: as indicated by RobW, this is not entirely the case; the API is present (even if that is not documented), but only affects content loaded inside the app, in a `<webview>` container.

Basically, you still cannot affect normal browsing, but have tools to affect external content used inside your app.

Comment: The `webRequest` API *is* supported in Chrome Apps, but only for the network activity within a [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

Comment: @RobW that makes sense. Can you make this into an answer?

Comment: Feel free to edit it into your answer. I think that the OP is asking whether it is possible to use the webRequest API in an App to get notified of activities in the regular browsing profile. You've correctly answered the question for that case.